# python syntax question: class instantiation with its argument outside brackets

Tags: python, class, syntax, casting

I cannot figure out what kind of python sytanx is used.
I hope someone could tell me.

```py
from pathlib import Path

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import torch
import torchvision.transforms as T
from torchvision.io import read_image


plt.rcParams["savefig.bbox"] = 'tight'
torch.manual_seed(1)


def show(imgs):
    fix, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=len(imgs), squeeze=False)
    for i, img in enumerate(imgs):
        img = T.ToPILImage()(img.to('cpu'))
        axs[0, i].imshow(np.asarray(img))
        axs[0, i].set(xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[], xticks=[], yticks=[])
```

The part I'm wondering is below.

```py
        img = T.ToPILImage()(img.to('cpu'))
```

`ToPILImage()` class instantiating with an image object, not as its argument but outside the brackets.

The code is from this page.
https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/auto_examples/plot_scripted_tensor_transforms.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-scripted-tensor-transforms-py

The source code of `ToPILImage()` is from the page link below.
https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/_modules/torchvision/transforms/transforms.html#ToPILImage

On that page, three special methods (`__init__`, `__call__`, `__repr__`) for the class are defined only.

```py
class ToPILImage:
    """Convert a tensor or an ndarray to PIL Image. This transform does not support torchscript.

    Converts a torch.*Tensor of shape C x H x W or a numpy ndarray of shape
    H x W x C to a PIL Image while preserving the value range.

    Args:
        mode (`PIL.Image mode`_): color space and pixel depth of input data (optional).
            If ``mode`` is ``None`` (default) there are some assumptions made about the input data:
            - If the input has 4 channels, the ``mode`` is assumed to be ``RGBA``.
            - If the input has 3 channels, the ``mode`` is assumed to be ``RGB``.
            - If the input has 2 channels, the ``mode`` is assumed to be ``LA``.
            - If the input has 1 channel, the ``mode`` is determined by the data type (i.e ``int``, ``float``,
            ``short``).

    .. _PIL.Image mode: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes
    """

    def __init__(self, mode=None):
        _log_api_usage_once(self)
        self.mode = mode

    def __call__(self, pic):
        """
        Args:
            pic (Tensor or numpy.ndarray): Image to be converted to PIL Image.

        Returns:
            PIL Image: Image converted to PIL Image.

        """
        return F.to_pil_image(pic, self.mode)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        format_string = self.__class__.__name__ + "("
        if self.mode is not None:
            format_string += f"mode={self.mode}"
        format_string += ")"
        return format_string
```

My guess is

- the `__init__` is called in that process.
- object cast is in the process.

But I don't know how those two are linked in that call ?

Comment: There's no object casting going on. The `ToPILImage` object is simply calling it's magic `__call__` method. It's the magic function that's called when trying to run an object as a function.

Comment: @AbirbhavG. oh .. it was not `__init__` but `__call__`. Never used the special method.

Comment: @Woodford thank you for the reference ! I throughly read it. With that reference and the answer from Alec Petersen cleared it up !

Answer (score 1):

```
img = T.ToPILImage()(img.to('cpu'))
```

`T.ToPILImage()` must return some callable object (likely a class).

Then this object is called, with `img.to('cpu')` as an argument.

If it helps, think of the code this way:

```
myclass = T.ToPILImage()
img = myclass(img.to('cpu'))
```

Comment: Thank you,  the example code was very easy to follow !

Answer (score 1):

It's not instantiating with the image object as an argument. The class is instantiated with `T.ToPILImage()` (this is when `__init__` is run), it is then *called* (hence the implementation of the `__call__` method) with the image as an argument (like a function).

A simple example:

```
class Add:
    def __call__(self, x, y):
        return x + y

adder = Add()
summed = adder(1, 3)
print(summed)
```

Comment: Thank you !!! It all made sense with the example.